# stuck at laravel, trying to store an id in a variable

Tags: php, laravel

I want to store the user_id in the profile table into a variable. In my index function I have:

```
$userid = Profile::where('user_id', auth()->user()->id)
            ->first();

        return view ('profile.index',[
            'user' => $user,
            'userid' => $userid,
          'about' => $about,
```

and in my index view:

```
@if(Auth::user()->id == $userid)
        <h3>hello</h3>
     @endif
```

Yet, I get this error:

Object of class App\Models\Profile could not be converted to int (View: C:\xampp\laravelprojects\testfrihand\resources\views\profile\index.blade.php)

Comment: `$user_id` isn't an id it is an instance of the `Profile` model that you queried for ... also all you are doing here is comparing the same value to itself in your logic

Comment: That's true, it makes sense now.

Answer (score 2):

Change it to get `user_id` from the model instance

```
$userid = Profile::where('user_id', auth()->id)
            ->first()->user_id;
```

*Notice1*: When you call `first()` method, you'll get an instance of eloquent model. You should tell it what attribute do you want. Here, you want user_id. Either `->first()->user_id` and `->first()->get('user_id')` will give your desired answer.

*Notice2*: You can get id of current authenticated user by calling `auth()->id`

Comment: You are a life saver man, was scratching my head for an hour. I owe you one!

Answer (score 0):

Not actually understand what do you need exactly.
But anywhere
$userid = Profile::where('user_id', auth()->user()->id)
->first();
Here you get a Profile Object, not an id.
Please specify your question: do you want to store user_id in this code, or to get user_id and use it in condition?

Comment: I want to get the user_id and use it in a condition. If the currently logged in user @if(Auth::user()->id == $user)   a navbar @endif

Comment: @Dmitry Ocheretko SO is Q&A, if you need to pose questions about questions, please use comments.

Answer (score -1):

```
$user = auth()->user();
$whatEverYouWant= Profile::where('user_id', $user->id)->first();

return view ('profile.index',[
            'user' => $user,
            'userid' => $user->id,
          'about' => $about
]
```

Comment: A little explanation might be helpful. What was the problem and how did you solve it?

Comment: I want to store the user's id in a variable and use it in a condition to hide and show an html element. It's for a profile sidebar that will only be displayed for the logged in user, but when a user or guest visits another profile he should not be able to see that profile

Comment: @showdev I still haven't solved it, which is frustrating because I know the answer should be really simple

Comment: @CarlMenger It looked like [BABAK ASHRAFI](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66091557/924299) answered your question. Is that not the case?